Why are they sometimes inconsistent? value of java.sql.Date type received from server then converted by google.gson .A json string sent from server
Why are the dates sometimes inconsistent? Value of java.sql.Date type received from client Postman then is deserialized by com.google.gson.Gson (and before instantiating the Gson instance, I register two adapters -- one for deserializing java.sql.Date, another for deserializing java.sql.Time). And a JSON string sent from client.
I try to send a request from Postman to Tomcat v9.0 and deserialized the raw data (here is a JSON string) to DietDiary object which contain two fields with type java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time using com.google.gson package.
Two keys of raw data of request in Postman.
"createDate":"2022-05-05",
"createTime":"12:00:00", 


But the console in Eclipse prints
Ready to deserialize.
dietDiary:DietDiary [diaryId=2, userId=2, createDate=2021-12-26, createTime=00:00:00, totalFat=2.52, totalCarbon=2.3, totalProtein=2.1, totalFiber=2.1, totalSugar=1.2, totalSodium=1.1, totalCalories=1.21]

I don't know why?
Detailed info
Here is detailed info.

Client: Postman

Request method: GET

URL: http://localhost:8080/HealthHelper/dietDiary/test

Raw data: A JSON string:
{
    "diaryId":2,
    "userId":2,
    "createDate":"2022-05-05",
    "createTime":"12:00:00",  
    "totalFat":2.52,
    "totalCarbon":2.3,
    "totalProtein":2.1,
    "totalFiber":2.1,
    "totalSugar":1.2,
    "totalSodium":1.1,
    "totalCalories":1.21 
}


Client Tomcat v9.0


Code
In /HealthHelper/src/main/java/controller/TestController.java
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import constant.SqlDatePattern;
import constant.SqlTimePattern;
import util.gson.GsonForSqlDateAndSqlTime;
import util.gson.deserializer.JsonDeserializerForSqTime;
import util.gson.deserializer.JsonDeserializerForSqlDate;
import vo.DietDiary;

@WebServlet("/dietDiary/test")
public class TestController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {  
        Gson gson = GsonForSqlDateAndSqlTime.gson;
        DietDiary dietDiary = gson.fromJson(req.getReader(), DietDiary.class);
        
        System.out.println("Ready to deserialize.");
        System.out.println("dietDiary:"+dietDiary);
    }
}

In /HealthHelper/src/main/java/vo/DietDiary.java
A class that satisfies JavaBean rule and not be polluted.
package vo;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

public class DietDiary {
    private int diaryId;
    private int userId;
    private Date createDate;
    private Time createTime;
    private Double totalFat;
    private Double totalCarbon;
    private Double totalProtein;
    private Double totalFiber;
    private Double totalSugar;
    private Double totalSodium;
    private Double totalCalories;
    
    public int getDiaryId() {
        return diaryId;
    }
    public void setDiaryId(int diaryId) {
        this.diaryId = diaryId;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }
    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }
    public Time getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }
    public void setCreateTime(Time createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }
    public Double getTotalFat() {
        return totalFat;
    }
    public void setTotalFat(Double totalFat) {
        this.totalFat = totalFat;
    }
    public Double getTotalCarbon() {
        return totalCarbon;
    }
    public void setTotalCarbon(Double totalCarbon) {
        this.totalCarbon = totalCarbon;
    }
    public Double getTotalProtein() {
        return totalProtein;
    }
    public void setTotalProtein(Double totalProtein) {
        this.totalProtein = totalProtein;
    }
    public Double getTotalFiber() {
        return totalFiber;
    }
    public void setTotalFiber(Double totalFiber) {
        this.totalFiber = totalFiber;
    }
    public Double getTotalSugar() {
        return totalSugar;
    }
    public void setTotalSugar(Double totalSugar) {
        this.totalSugar = totalSugar;
    }
    public Double getTotalSodium() {
        return totalSodium;
    }
    public void setTotalSodium(Double totalSodium) {
        this.totalSodium = totalSodium;
    }
    public Double getTotalCalories() {
        return totalCalories;
    }
    public void setTotalCalories(Double totalCalories) {
        this.totalCalories = totalCalories;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof DietDiary) {
            return false;
        }
        
        DietDiary dietDiary = (DietDiary) object;
        
        if(!Objects.equals(this.getUserId(),dietDiary.getUserId()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if(!Objects.equals(this.getUserId(),dietDiary.getUserId()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if(!Objects.equals(this.getCreateDate(),dietDiary.getCreateDate()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if(!Objects.equals(this.getCreateDate(),dietDiary.getCreateTime()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DietDiary [diaryId=" + diaryId + ", userId=" + userId + ", createDate=" + createDate + ", createTime="
                + createTime + ", totalFat=" + totalFat + ", totalCarbon=" + totalCarbon + ", totalProtein="
                + totalProtein + ", totalFiber=" + totalFiber + ", totalSugar=" + totalSugar + ", totalSodium="
                + totalSodium + ", totalCalories=" + totalCalories + "]";
    }
    
}

In /HealthHelper/src/main/java/util/gson/GsonForSqlDateAndSqlTime.java
I put a Gson instance whose adapters are registered for deserialized java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time in GsonForSqlDateAndSqlTime public class
package util.gson;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import util.gson.deserializer.JsonDeserializerForSqTime;
import util.gson.deserializer.JsonDeserializerForSqlDate;

public class GsonForSqlDateAndSqlTime {
    public static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, JsonDeserializerForSqlDate.dateDeserializer)
            .registerTypeAdapter(Time.class, JsonDeserializerForSqTime.timeDeserializer)
            .create();
}

In /HealthHelper/src/main/java/util/gson/deserializer/JsonDeserializerForSqlDate.java
package util.gson.deserializer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import constant.SqlDatePattern;

public class JsonDeserializerForSqlDate {
    public static JsonDeserializer<Date> dateDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SqlDatePattern.sqlDatePattern);
            try {
                return new Date(dateFormat.parse(json.getAsString()).getTime());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new JsonParseException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}

In /HealthHelper/src/main/java/util/gson/deserializer/JsonDeserializerForSqTime.java
package util.gson.deserializer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import constant.SqlTimePattern;

public class JsonDeserializerForSqTime {
    public static JsonDeserializer<Time> timeDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<Time>() {
        @Override
        public Time deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SqlTimePattern.sqlTimePattern);
            try {
                return new Time(timeFormat.parse(json.getAsString()).getTime());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new JsonParseException(e);
            }
        }
    };
}

What did I try?
I have read these docs.

API about JsonDeserializer interface in com.google.gson package


You should be using java.time.LocalDate in your bean btw, or java.util.LocalDateTime

Appreciations, thanks, salutions should be removed. It is explained in the guidelines. Only information that is rekevant is needed.

Use Instant or OffsetDateTime or ZonedDateTime for the time your diary was created. They are from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time classes were badlydesigned, both of them true hacks on top of the already poorly designed java.util.Date class. All of those have been outdated the last 10 years.

In your equals method == will not work for comparing date and time (no matter if you use the modern or the outdated types). Use this.getCreateDate().equals(dietDiary.getCreateDate()). Or if the date may be null, then Objects.equals().

You've mixed up client and server. Your client is Postman, and the server is Tomcat.

Thanks to fix my mistype on question.

I have fix the term and the wrong code.

I have found the cause. The reason why seems obvious.
I misused the flag to create a java.text.SimpleDateFormat instance (occurred in /HealthHelper/src/main/java/util/gson/deserializer/JsonDeserializerForSqlDate.java) so that the java.sql.Date parsing is wrong.
In this statement
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SqlDatePattern.sqlDatePattern);

the static field SqlDatePattern.sqlDatePattern is assigned to yyyy-MM-DD.
I changed it into yyyy-MM-dd.
I also changed SqlTimePattern.sqlTimePattern from hh:mm:ss to HH:mm:ss in the following statement.
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SqlTimePattern.sqlTimePattern);

Then I test it again, getting expected results.
In console in Eclipse, it prints
Ready to deserialize.
dietDiary:DietDiary [diaryId=2, userId=2, createDate=2022-05-05, createTime=12:00:00, totalFat=2.52, totalCarbon=2.3, totalProtein=2.1, totalFiber=2.1, totalSugar=1.2, totalSodium=1.1, totalCalories=1.21]


These terribly-flawed date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310, built into Java 8+. There is no reason to be using them in 2024.

@BasilBourque But you can still make the same mistake with those classes.

@BasilBourque because I want to store the data into a MySQL table contains two fields Date and Time

java.time.LocalDate and java.time.LocalTime.
